# kafka put back message to queue, is it OK?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I want to know wether is it possible to put message back to queue from kafka consumer? What is the best practices?

My case is :

I have kafka queue message A B C, then the consumer take A, process it, the queue become B C and something bad happens, then I want to put it back to queue. The last state is B C A. And i dont want retry.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In kafka, each partition is an ordered, `immutable` sequence of messages that is continually appended to a commit log. 
`It is impossible` to put failed message back and change the order of failed message.(from ABC to BCA).

Usually when the consumer take A and are not able to consume it in first time, you can retry it or manually control the consumer offset and do not commit it.
(You cou refer to [Manual Offset Control](http://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html) for details)

Comment: I mean insert A as new queue message, is it possible ? but thanks for the Manual Offset Control reference. I'll read it

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Once message handle failed, send it to new queue(retry queue) and re-consume it later.